# GPG Key generation failed: End of file

Tags: github, gnupg

I'm trying to generate a GPG Key following this tutorial: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/generating-a-new-gpg-key but I'm getting the following **End of file** error:

```
% gpg --full-generate-key                     
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.6; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA
   (2) DSA and Elgamal
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
   (9) ECC (sign and encrypt) *default*
  (10) ECC (sign only)
  (14) Existing key from card
Your selection? 1
RSA keys may be between 1024 and 4096 bits long.
What keysize do you want? (3072) 4096
Requested keysize is 4096 bits
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
Key is valid for? (0) 0
Key does not expire at all
Is this correct? (y/N) y

GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

Real name: name
Email address: email
Comment: comment
You selected this USER-ID:
    "name (comment) <email>"

Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? o
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: agent_genkey failed: End of file
Key generation failed: End of file
```

Versions:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.6
libgcrypt 1.10.1
```

Do you know how can I solve this **End of file** issue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using MacOS? I've had the same problem with the currently latest GnuPG OSX version (2.3.6) which didn't work for me either. Try using LTS version (2.2.35). It worked fine for me.

Link: https://sourceforge.net/p/gpgosx/docu/Download/

Comment: I had the same issue on an M1 Macbook Air running gpg Stable (2.3.6) downloaded from gnupg.org. The failures also manifested as a dyld error when trying to import a key. Downgrading to the LTS (2.2.35) resolved both issues. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue with a M1 too and it solved the problem to pass to LTS